# leaflet on android app with GPS localisation

Tags: leaflet

I put my leaflet html code on android webview component and it works awsome like native app of maps ,but the GPS location doesn't work .
[mycode](https://plnkr.co/edit/vIo38l5Zq2mQ1YAXxKkN?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>GIS</title>
<meta http-equiv='content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://domoritz.github.io/leaflet-locatecontrol/dist/L.Control.Locate.min.css"/>
<style>
 html, body, #map {
             height: 100%;
            }
            body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://domoritz.github.io/leaflet-locatecontrol/dist/L.Control.Locate.min.js"></script>
<script>
var mymap=L.map('map',{attributionControl: false,center : [36.643905,4.903630],zoom: 18,minZoom:7,maxZoom: 22,zoomControl:false});
var GRaster = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']});
var OSMRoads =  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(mymap);


 //GPS
    L.control.locate().addTo(mymap);
      L.control.layers({
    'Satelite image' :GRaster,
    'Road maps':OSMRoads
    }).addTo(mymap);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: There are several things that have to be considered when using geolocation in WebView on Android. They are covered in answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation

Comment: I did a change based on the link you provided but now I get an Error: application does not have sufficient geolocation permission

Comment: In Android go to Settings > Apps > Your app > Permissions and enable Location permission.

Comment: On an Android 6 or 7 phone in build.gradle file: must be 
targetSdkVersion 21

Comment: How to get GPS without internet because in this I found that internet is necessary

Comment: For GPS you don't need internet, you need it for on-line maps. If you have off-line maps stored on your Android device, GPS works just fine without internet.

And by the way, if any of the above comments helped you, mark them as such or write about it. Q&A is not only for you but for anybody with similar problems.

Comment: I have android 7 so when I changed the targetSdkVersion to 21 on build.gradle file the problem was solved.Now I build leaflet maps offline but I noticed that the GPS can't show me my location unless I get online when I run my offline leaflet map on my browser on my localhost when I request the GPS like I do on my android app based on webview I get the error message Geolocation error: Network location provider at https:wwwgooglepis.com :No responce received..Is this means that internet is needed on leaflet GPS ?

Comment: Error message shows that your Android GPS does not use satellite GPS but mobile or WiFi geolocation. The definition says: The Google Maps Geolocation API also called google-geolocation api is an web interface that can return a location and accuracy radius based on information about cell towers and WiFi nodes that the mobile client can detect.

Comment: I understand now  it is a setting on my mobile geolocalisation I fixed it and all is working ,thanks